# PHP Array image url text to src

Tags: php, arrays, image, decode

I have some problem with Arrays. I have this code:

```
$image_array = array(
    "image" => "images/4iJfYYoQzZcONB9hNzg0J0wWyPH.jpg",
    "user" => "itsme",
    "year" => 2014
);
```

How can I convert this to:

```
<img src="images/4iJfYYoQzZcONB9hNzg0J0wWyPH.jpg" >
```

Thank you!

Comment: `echo "<img src=\"{$array['image']}\">";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this where you want it.
Assuming the Array is stored in the variable `$array`

```
<img src="<?=$array['image'];?>" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic question, so maybe you should learn how to use [Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing) first.

Then you can answer your question yourself.

Answer (score 1):

When you need a specific functionality in your code and it is going to be reused several times, it is better to make it in a function let us apply your requirement in a function as follows:

```
function printImg($arr){
   $format = "<img src=\"%s\" />";
   sprintf($format, $arr['image']);
}
```

Then in anywhere you want to have the image tag:

```
<?php echo printImg($arr); ?>
```

Where $arr is the variable array name for the code you regarded. This is making cleaner and reusable code.

If you don't want to use echo you may use `printf()` in the function's code instead of `sprintf()`